# Deleting file if it crashes my app (2)

Tags: java, error-handling, crash

ok so i've nearly got this. But it seems there is some logic error that i can't get around. Note that i cannot use try/catch. No need to ask why

---

EDIT

```
for(String File : List){


        final String FilePath = getPath() + "/" + File;
        Render renderer = renderFile(FilePath);
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(){
             public void run() {
                    deleteFile(FilePath);
                }
            });

        deleteFile(FilePath);
        updateReport(stuff);
        writeReportToFile(Report.toString());
```

I want it to delete the file that's causing my crash .. if the app crashes but it doesn't seem to be working. Am i calling it wrongly or what? *confused*

FINAL EDIT

OK after much toying around i finally got it to work!! Thanks everyone

Comment: why delete it? Cant you just clear it?

Comment: that app processes pictures in an array, and all of the pictures are in one folder, so  i can't clear the entire folder

Comment: More code that shows the flow, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your last question I see, that you

- process images,
- one or more images will crash the JVM,
- we can't catch that exception/error and
- we want to delete the corrupt image on the next run

An easy solution goes like that:

1. Each time, before you read bytes from an image file, persist the name of that image to a file (like: `processingImage.txt`)
2. Each time, an image has been processed succesfully, delete `processingImage.txt`
3. If the application crashes, then `processingImage.txt` contains the name of the offending image
4. If you start the application, check if `processingImage.txt` exists, read the name of the image, delete the image and delete `processingImage.txt`.

Comment: If you strictly follow *this* algorithm, it will only delete the file named in `processingImage.txt` (unless *every* file in your folder crashes your program, then, indeed, it will *always* delete the first image ;) )

Answer (score 0):

I have a bad feeling about this, but you could add a shutdown hook on your application. (Be warned, while the shutdown hooks are processed, the only way to kill your application is via task manager - so be sure that your shutdown hook really works/does not take forever/does not cause deadlocks)

The following `main`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
        public void run() {
                System.out.println("I'm called on shutown.");
            }
        });
    throw new RuntimeException("Uncaught Exception");
}
```

prints this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncaught Exception
    at stackoverflowtests.ShutdownHookTester.main(ShutdownHookTester.java:11)
I'm called on shutown.
```

Comment: where do i declare the main? since my app just uses methods

Comment: The main was just to demontrate (and to test before I post it) that the hooks are also executed if the application crashes with uncaught exceptions. The `Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHoock(...)` method can be called from everywhere.